# Limit for css values (left: - 17000000px; )

Tags: html, css

Here (http://jsfiddle.net/sgva97xd/5/) you can see that it is possible to have values like 17 millions (!) for `left` :

CSS:

```
#container { 
    position: absolute;
    left:-17000000px; 
} 
#blah { 
    position: absolute;
    left:17000040px; 
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="container"><div id="blah">Blah</div></div>
```

When I replace these values by 18 millions, it doesn't work anymore (on Firefox).
**What is the exact limit for CSS values of `top`, `left`, etc. ?**

---

*Note : it might be unuseful to be able to go to values like millions, but it's just for testing purpose.*

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work anymore"? For me any value I give it still works

Comment: Nothing at all is displayed when I use `18000000` and `18000040`, whereas 'Blah' is correctly displayed if I use 17 millions (using Firefox).

Comment: What you're asking and what you show in the demo are two different issues. What you're asking is "what is the max of an element's position". What the demo is showing is "what is the max offset for one parent in order for the child to be rendered correctly"

Comment: Chrome (14.0) :    `134,217,726 px`
Safari (5.1)  :    `134,217,726 px`
IE (9.0)      :    `10,737,418 px`
FF (7.0.1)    :    `17,895,697 px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [**W3 docs on Values and Units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths)

> CSS theoretically supports infinite precision and infinite ranges for all value types; however in reality implementations have finite capacity. UAs should support reasonably useful ranges and precisions.

So, answering your question: **What is the exact limit for CSS values of top, left, etc. ?**

There is no *exact* defined limit. It may vary from browser to browser...